# I want to remove specific filenames but keep specific ones

Tags: powershell, rename

Hi I want to remove random words in the filename but keep some of them

Example:

Original filename;

- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - Pain, Scar & Muscle Relaxant - Fenoprofen 200 mg
- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - Pain & Scar - Lidocaine 7% 7%
- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - Pain, Dermatitis & Muscle Relaxant - Doxepin 5 mg

What should it look like:

- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - Pain - Fenoprofen 200mg
- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - Pain - Lidocaine 7% 7%
- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - Pain - Doxepin 5 mg

Thank you.

Comment: "I don't know how to apply sample codes"... SO is for help with specific issues and problems which requires a minimal reproducible issue. Please provide what you have tried so far along with the specific issues you are getting. You really shouldn't be writing code if you have "no clue at all in coding".

Comment: If you want to do a simple text replace, you can use the String class `Replace` method: `'Pain, Scar & Muscle Relaxant - Fenoprofen Pain & Scar - Lidocaine Pain, Dermatitis & Muscle Relaxant - Doxepin'.Replace(', Scar & Muscle Relaxant',$null)`

Comment: @I.TDelinquent I'm sorry that's the reason why I'm trying to figure it out I dont know where to start. If you wont help me thats fine.

Comment: @GabrielBalenton Right now your question shows no previous attempt at even researching the thing you want to do. Please use a dedicated tutorial or training service as SO doesn't provide training in the way you are wanting.

Comment: @I.TDelinquent I've tried this actually,

`get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "Pain & Scar ","Pain" }
get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "Pain & Dermatitis ","Pain" }
get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "Pain & Muscle Relaxant ","Pain" }
get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "Pain & Metabolic ","Pain" }`

The list goes on. The problem is if there is a code that could do the trick for all

Comment: @GabrielBalenton Please update your question with what you have tried so far. In future, this information is really important in helping you once you have a good foundation of the issue and resolution path :)

Comment: If these examples are filenames, do they not have an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with something similar to below. It assumes you want to replace text between `Pain` and space plus hyphen.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "*Pain*" -File |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '(?<=\bPain\b).*(?= -)'} -WhatIf
```

**Explanation:**

`Get-ChildItem -Path "*Pain*" -File` will return all files in the current directory that contain `Pain` in the name. You can add the `-Recurse` parameter to find all files in child directories that meet the criteria.

Since `Rename-Item -NewName` supports delayed script binding, we can simply pipe the `Get-ChildItem` results into it and access the `Name` property.

`-replace` is the replace operator that does regex matching.

- `(?<=\bPain\b)` is a positive lookbehind assertion that ensures the file name contains the word `Pain` and won't start matching characters until that condition is met.
- `.*` matches 0 or more characters except newline characters.
- `(?= -)` is a positive lookahead assertion that ensures the current match has `-` (single space plus -) after it.

The effect of the `-replace` operation is replace all characters between `Pain` and `-`. It can easily be adjusted for different scenarios. The more you know about your data, the better you can define your regex.

You can add the `-PassThru` switch to `Rename-Item` if you want an output of the renamed files.

See [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FwecyW/1) to see how the `-replace` regex matching works. See [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-5.1) specifically the `-NewName` section and Example 4 for more information on using the `-NewName` parameter with replace.

Comment: Hi,

I've tried the code but did not do anything. Here's the exact code that I used

`cd "C:\Users\eulla\Documents\GAB\ZZZZ"
Get-ChildItem -Path "Pain*" -File |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '(?<=^Pain).*(?= -)'}`

and the exact filename to be replaced:

RX Insurance Marketing Solutions PPLLC - Dr.  Smith - John Smith - OH - Pain, Scar & Muscle Relaxant - Fenoprofen 200 mg

Needs to be:

RX Insurance Marketing Solutions PPLLC - Dr.  Smith - John Smith - OH - Pain - Fenoprofen 200 mg

Comment: did you run `Get-ChildItem -Path "Pain*" -File` afterwards and see the result?

Comment: Yes I did but apparently it did not do anything.

Comment: So this code is an example of what you can do. If it did absolutely nothing, then your current directory has no matching files.

Comment: It actually has files with Pain, Scar & Muscle Relaxant & Pain & Muscle Relaxant renaming like 50 worth of files. I dont know what seems to be the problem with the code that I am using.

Comment: So in your scenario, you have no dashes in the files. In your posted example, all of your files have dashes. The code currently relies on dashes. If you want concise code, you will have to determine the pattern of your file names. Can you explicitly point out how you want the rename to happen as in define the rules for the rename?

Comment: So the rule is I want the current rename **"RX PPLLC - Dr.  Smith - John Smith - OH - Pain, Scar & Muscle Relaxant - Fenoprofen 200 mg"** to be **"RX PPLLC - Dr.  Smith - John Smith - OH - Pain - Fenoprofen 200 mg"**. So removing **,Scar & Muscle Relaxant** out of the file name but at the same time keeping Fenoprofen or whatever word it is.

Comment: So that is a good example but only one. Do all of the strings you want to remove begin with a `,` contain a `&`, and eventually run into a `-`?

Comment: Yes they do. Like **Pain & Scar** or **Pain, Scar & Muscle Relaxant**.

Comment: Does the section of the file name you want altered always begin with `Pain`?

Comment: @GabrielBalenton Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57975218/edit) your question and give us a couple of _REAL_ example filenames because apparently the word 'Pain' is not always the first word of the filename. Also make it clear what to do with `200 mg` or whatever ends the filename. As it is now, your question raises more questions than applicable answers..

Comment: Yes it always begins with Pain. So to be exact it looks like this **Pain & Scar - Lidocaine 7% 7% mg** or **Pain, Scar & Muscle Relaxant - Fenoprofen 200 mg** it should look like this **Pain - Lidocaine7% 7% mg** or **Pain - Fenoprofen 200 mg** so as you can see the last words they are not the same.

Comment: @GabrielBalenton I made a code update that should help.

Comment: Thank you soo much it did actually work sorry I was not very specific with my question. Next time I will be

Comment: @GabrielBalenton No, the filenames do NOT always start with 'Pain' as shows in your updated examples. This is why I deleted my answer, because you are not clear in what the names are and what the result of the rename should be.